# Is there any dynamic line chart in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, line, charts

I want a line graph or chart which moves dynamically like windows task manager (performance tab). Is there any plugin like that?

Comment: Have you tried googling your very question title? http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+line+chart+jquery

Answer (score 1):

Check out Highcharts. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score -1):

I think [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is becoming the leader of the pack. I used it and it was quite straightforward.